# Can I ask my professor to allot me mentor while I am doing reading work for a theoretical project?

Tags: thesis, masters, physics, projects, thesis-committee

I am a master's student in Physics and currently working on my thesis work and I am having a hard time grasping some mathematical concepts needed. Most of my friends are working on simulation work, and they all are allotted Ph.D. mentors, which helps them in several ways since profs aren't always available and take time to respond to emails. But since I am doing reading for my theoretical work, should I ask my guide to allot me one as well?  I don't know if I can have one in such work.

I think it will help me to understand mathematical tools and to think from different perspectives. I do have weekly meetings with my professor, for doubts and discussions. Please let me know.

Comment: Are there PhD students in your lab that would be appropriate mentors?

Comment: Can you not approach other PhD students directly (face-to-face or via mail) because they were tutors/TAs in one of your seminars?

Comment: @BryanKrause  My professor told me one Ph.D. student works in the same field.

Comment: @Stefan_W  I don't know anyone from this field yet. I can, if I get to know someone.

Comment: Why do you doubt the appropriateness?

Comment: @Buffy appropriateness of what?

Comment: The appropriateness of asking. It seems if others have such mentors then it is common and accepted.

Comment: @Buffy Others are doing computational work mostly simulation. While mine is basically reading and doing mathematics, so I was sceptical.

Comment: You can ask. We cannot tell you what the answer will be.

Comment: @ChristianHennig alright